# In Phoenix Live View I am getting ** (ArgumentError) nil given for `token` when trying to access @current_user for a not logged in user

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

The error I am getting is:

```
** (ArgumentError) nil given for `token`. comparison with nil is forbidden as it is unsafe. Instead write a query with is_nil/1, for example: is_nil(s.token)
```

I am trying to create a logic for showing things for **visitors VS logged-in users**.

For logged in users I can use @current_user.email etc. in my templates but not for just visitors (people who are not logged in)

So, I have this in my live view page `home_page_live.ex`:

```
def mount(_params, session, socket) do
  socket =
    socket
    |> assign(:welcome_message, "Hello, visitor!")
    |> assign_current_user(session)

  {:ok, socket}
end
```

and the `assign_current_user()` function is in my `live_helpers.ex`

```
def assign_current_user(socket, session) do
  assign_new(
    socket,
    :current_user,
    fn ->
      Accounts.get_user_by_session_token(session["user_token"])
    end
  )
end
```

Any idea how can I incorporate the `is_nil()` function (that the error message is suggesting to me) so this works, not only for logged in users, but also for not logged in users on my home page? So, I am able to do something like:

```
<%= if @current_user do %>
  <%= @current_user.email %>
<% else %>
  Hello, not-logged-in user!
<% end %>
```

Currently, my assumption is that the `current_user` **is nil and not a map**, so, it terminates everything and Phoenix crashes for some internal Phoenix reasons. But I have no idea how to make it work.

Do you know what to do, so it works for both logged-in and not logged-in users?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Any idea, guys? ;(

Comment: Maybe Unauthenticated Users and Authenticated Users should be routed to go to different pages?

Comment: For the Unathuneticated users, does `user_token` come back as `nil` in `session` session, or is just missing from the `session` map entirely?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding pattern matching and a guard for the condition when `user_token` is `nil`.

```
def assign_current_user(socket, %{"user_token" => user_token} = session) when is_nil(user_token) do
  assign_new(socket, :current_user, nil)
end
def assign_current_user(socket, %{"user_token" => user_token} = session) do 
  assign_new(
    socket,
    :current_user,
    fn ->
      Accounts.get_user_by_session_token(user_token)
    end
  )
def assign_current_user(socket, session) do: socket
```